# generate a sequence with different lengths

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, algorithm, sequence

I am trying to write code that can generate a sequence that can be generalized with any sequence:

```
1     0:0
2     0:1
3     0:2
.     .
.     .
59    0:58
60    0:59
61    1:0
62    1:1
63    1:2
.     .
.     .
119   1:58
120   1:59
121   2:0
122   2:1
123   2:2
.     .
.     .
.     .
16383 273:2     
16384 273:3
```

The whole data sample can be found publicly in [Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13zuUkpaKym7yqTOu4I41woZBCWepnkVEr1S4C1rU77k/edit?usp=sharing).

I could find out that the sequence always starts with fixed sequence `0..59` but at the end it is just `0..3` which made it difficult for me to write the formula that can be generalized to any sequence of any length (in this example the sequence length is 16385 but it can be of any length where the sequence `0..59` is always there)

I tried the following:

```py
s = list()
for h in range(16385): # this index can be different; like 20000 or any
    for m in range(60): # always fixed number = 60
        s.append(f'{h}:{m}')
```

This code snippet even when it reaches the end with `0..59`, it continues and these are the last 5 elements of `s`;

`s[-5:] => ['16384:55', '16384:56', '16384:57', '16384:58', '16384:59']`

Whereas the expected output should be like:
`s[-2:] => ['273:2', '273:3']`
I am not sure how to generalize this.

Comment: Assuming the input is minutes, you need to divide by 60 to get the number of hours.

Comment: Could you clarify, please?

Comment: Wouldn't just a simple `if` and `else` statement do the job?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure this is exactly what you were asking for, but it may help you to play around with some approaches to find your solution.

```
# A short way
print([f'{x%(60*60)}:{x%60}' for x in range(20000)])

# A little bit more precise
s = list()
amount = 20000
[s.append(f'{x%(60*60)}:{x%60}') for x in range(amount)]
print(s)

# A precise way
s = list()
amount = 20000
for x in range(amount):
    hours = x%(60*60)
    minutes = x%60
    s.append(f"{hours}:{minutes}")
print(s)
```

UPD:
Maybe I understood you. you just need hrs and mins, hence it's better just to iterate:

```
s = list()
amount = 2000
for h in range(amount):
    hours = h%(60*60)
    for m in range(60):
        minutes = m
        s.append(f"{hours}:{minutes}")
print(s)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Valerri. But when I set `mount = 16385` the last 2values of `s` where `['1984:58', '1984:59']` instead of `['273:2', '273:3']`

Comment: 'mount = 16385' isn't hours, it is just an index.

Comment: if I check `s.index('273:2')` I find `16382` where the sequence must end.

Comment: @Joe Well, it is even easier, just basic arithmetic 
print([f'{i//60}:{i%(60)}' for i in range(16385)])

Comment: In your case the number 16385 is amount of minutes, hence we got 16385/60=273 (hours)

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
output = [f'{int(index/60)}:{index%60}' for index in range(16384)]
print(output[-2:])
```

And the output will be:

```
['273:2', '273:3']
```

Notice that the indices start with 0 (not 1).

Answer (score 0):

Try this :
[f'{(x-1)//60}:{(x-1)%60}' for x in (1,100, 16381)]

or
[f'{int((x-1)/60)}:{(x-1)%60}' for x in (1,100, 16381)]

Answer (score -1):

```py
behind_tuple = tuple(i for i in range(60))
front_tuple = tuple(i for i in range(280))
final = tuple(f'{f}:{b}' for f in front_tuple for b in behind_tuple)
print(final.index('273:2'))

"""
16382
"""
```